# Output of teams with more than a half wins (Example: 3/5)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (Meetings) which contains the following columns:

```
HomeTeam(varchar)
AwayTeam(varchar)
Home(int)
Away(int)
```

My problem is that I need to output all teams which have more than a half wins.

The code provided below is working perfectly for the output, but I need to filter out the teams with more than a half wins. For Example:
Liverpool has won 3 out of 5 games, so I want it to be outputed, PSG has 4 out of 5 wins, so I want them also to be outputed. But Man United has only 2 wins out of 5 games and I do not want them in the output.

I am using MSSQL Server 18.

```
SELECT T.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Meetings AS M
        WHERE (M.HomeTeam = T.Team and M.Home > M.Away) OR
              (M.AwayTeam = T.Team and M.Away > M.Home)
        GROUP BY COUNT(*) > 2
       ) AS Wins
FROM Teams AS T
```

The expected output is:

> From Juventus 2/5,
>   Man United 1/5, 
>   PSG 4/5,
>   Liverpool 3/5,
>    Barcelona 3/5,
>   Bayern Munchen 0/5,

I want in the output to be only PSG, Liverpool and Barcelona as they have more than a half wins.

Comment: Typo.. `(M.AwayTeam = T.Team and M.Away > M.Away)` should be `(M.AwayTeam = T.Team and M.Away > M.Home)` M.Away will never by greater than itself.

Comment: How will you handle ties?

Comment: I need only the wins, ties do not matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` twice `Teams` with `Meetings` (once for home games and once for away games), and then analyze and filter the output:

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    COALESCE(h.cnt_wins,  0) + COALESCE(a.cnt_wins,  0) total_wins,
    COALESCE(h.cnt_games, 0) + COALESCE(a.cnt_games, 0) total_games
FROM Teams t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        HomeTeam Team, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Home > Away THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cnt_wins,
        COUNT(*) cnt_games,
    FROM Meetings
    GROUP BY HomeTeam
) h ON m.Team = t.Team
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        AwayTeam Team, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN Home < Away THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cnt_wins,
        COUNT(*) cnt_games,
    FROM Meetings
    GROUP BY AwayTeam
) a ON a.Team = t.Team
WHERE 
    COALESCE(h.cnt_wins,  0) + COALESCE(a.cnt_wins,  0)
    > ( COALESCE(h.cnt_games, 0) + COALESCE(a.cnt_games, 0) ) / 2
```

Comment: Welcome @S1C4R10! Happy to help.

Comment: For only two parameters it is easier and clearer to use IsNull(), than COALESCE(). Though it is not a error by any chance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution in "one" statement, logically split in WITH statement:

```
DECLARE @Meetings TABLE (
    HomeTeam VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    AwayTeam VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Home INT NOT NULL,
    Away INT NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO @Meetings
(
    HomeTeam,
    AwayTeam,
    Home,
    Away
)
VALUES
('A', 'B', 2, 5),
('C', 'D', 1, 5), 
('A', 'D', 3, 2), 
('C', 'A', 1, 5), 
('C', 'B', 4, 2), 
('B', 'D', 1, 4) 



;WITH Teams AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT HomeTeam AS TeamName FROM @Meetings
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT AwayTeam FROM @Meetings
)
, TeamWins AS (
    SELECT T.TeamName, (HW.HomeWins + AW.AwayWins) Wins, GM.Games FROM Teams T
        OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT COUNT(*) HomeWins FROM @Meetings M WHERE M.HomeTeam = T.TeamName AND M.Home > M.Away) HW
        OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AwayWins FROM @Meetings M WHERE M.AwayTeam = T.TeamName AND M.Away > M.Home) AW
        OUTER APPLY
        (SELECT COUNT(*) Games FROM @Meetings M WHERE M.AwayTeam = T.TeamName) GM

)
SELECT * FROM TeamWins TW WHERE 2*TW.Wins > TW.Games
```

Output:

```
TeamName    Wins    Games
A           2       1
C           1       0
D           2       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer using a cte to organize the table in winners and losers

```
declare @t table (HomeTeam varchar(100),AwayTeam varchar(100),Home int, Away int)

-- determine winner and loser
;with cte as
(
select Outcome,Team
from @t
cross apply (values
                ('W'
                    , case when Home>Away
                        then HomeTeam
                        else AwayTeam end)
                ,('L', case when Home>Away
                            then AwayTeam
                            else HomeTeam end)) ca(Outcome,Team)

where Home<>Away
)
select Team
    ,wins = SUM(case when Outcome = 'W' then 1 else 0 end )
    ,Losses = SUM(case when Outcome = 'L' then 1 else 0 end )
    ,Rate = SUM(case when Outcome = 'W' then 1 else 0 end )/COUNT(*)
from cte
group by Team
having SUM(case when Outcome = 'W' then 1 else 0 end )/COUNT(*)>.5
```